# in Processing, how to hover over mouse to make numbers of rectangles change color?

Tags: processing

I've finished a single rectangle code, but I'd like to know ways to make at least four rectangles change color while hovering the mouse over them. Any advice is much appreciated.

code is below:

```
int rectX, rectY;  
int rectSize = 90;  
color rectColor;
color baseColor;

boolean rectOver = false;

void setup() {
  size(640, 360);
  rectColor = color(0);
  baseColor = color(102);
  rectX = width/2;
  rectY = height/2;
  rectMode(CENTER);
}

void draw() {
 update(mouseX, mouseY);

  noStroke();
  if (rectOver) {
    rectColor = color(255);
  }else 
  {
   rectColor = color(0);
}

  stroke(255);
  fill(rectColor);
  rect(rectX, rectY, rectSize, rectSize);
}

void update(int x, int y) {
if ( overRect(rectX, rectY, rectSize, rectSize) ) {
    rectOver = true;}
    else{rectOver = false;}
}
boolean overRect(int x, int y, int width, int height) {
  if (mouseX >= x-width/2 && mouseX <= x+width/2 && 
      mouseY >= y-height/2 && mouseY <= y+height/2) {
    return true;
  } 
  else {
    return false;
  }
}
```

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you have to fix your `overRect` function since `width` and `height` are built-in variables, secondly what you need to do is to declare a rectangle class that will contain the x,y, width and height of your rectangle, plus two methods: one to check if the mouse if hovering (using your old method) and one to self draw the rectangle. Lastly, you need an array to store your rectangles. Here is the final code:

```
int rectX, rectY;  
int rectSize = 90;  
color rectColor;
color baseColor;
ArrayList<rectangle> list;

boolean rectOver = false;

class rectangle { 
  float x,y,w,h; 

  rectangle (float y, float x,float w, float h) {  
    this.x = x; 
    this.y = y; 
    this.w = w; 
    this.h = h; 
  } 
  
  boolean checkInside() { 
    return overRect(x,y,w,h);
  } 
  
  void selfDraw(){
    
    if (this.checkInside()) {
      rectColor = color(255);
    }else 
    {
      rectColor = color(0);
    }
    
    stroke(255);
    fill(rectColor);
    rect(x, y, w, h);
  }
} 

void setup() {
  
  size(640, 360);
  
  rectMode(CENTER);
  
  list= new ArrayList<rectangle>();
  
  list.add(new rectangle(40,40,50,60));
  list.add(new rectangle(20,200,50,20));
  list.add(new rectangle(300,200,50,50));
  list.add(new rectangle(200,300,80,60));
}

void draw() {
  
      for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
      list.get(i).selfDraw();
    }
}

boolean overRect(float x, float y, float w, float h) {
  if (mouseX >= x-w/2 && mouseX <= x+w/2 && 
      mouseY >= y-h/2 && mouseY <= y+h/2) {
    return true;
  } 
  else {
    return false;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use inheritence. As in YOUSFI's answer, your nest net would be to build a rectangle class and write it's own mouse over function in there. Then, you can make an instance of that object in your main program and call it's mouseover function.

Instead of blindly copy pasting the code YOUSFI provided, my suggestion would be to read up on Object Oriented Programming or watch this introductory video series: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xG2Vbnv0wvg